# Cannot copy to the last cell in the range

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a code to loop though range of cells and copy certain data in a column. But everytime I run the code it just copies the last record and not all of them. The issue is somewhere in the destination line of code where it can't find the last unused cell. Any help will be very appreciated. Many Thanks.

```
Sub ImmoScout()

    Dim MyRange As Range, Mycell As Range, Mycell2 As String

    Set MyRange = Application.Selection
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each Mycell In MyRange
        Mycell2 = Mycell.Value
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
        Range("A1:BB34470").AutoFilter Field:=54, Criteria1:=Mycell2
        Range("AM1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            If Selection.Cells.Count < 1048576 Then
                Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("BP1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                Range("AU1").Activate
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("BQ1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If

    Next Mycell
   ' Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Try to **Step** through the code to locate the issue. See [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Hi Ashleedawg, the code runs without any errors. I tried to use locals window but it doesn't help as to why it couldn't find the last cell in col BP and BQ.

Comment: **Step**ping through the code and checking the values of your variables, and which ranges are **Select**ed at each step should help identify exactly where the problem is.  That's also what I would do to help - except I don't know which cells have data and which don't so I won't know what functions like `End` are doing in your case.  One example of something to find out is, what is this line actually *selecting*? `Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select`  I'm not say that's the problem, that's just one lie to check out of "all" of them

Comment: So Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select is selecting the filtered cells based on my Autofilter criteria. I checked that and it is selecting the right thing. Now I want to paste this selection in the first available blank cell in column BP. So I used the code Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("BP1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) to paste the selection in the first empty cell from the bottom. but it just remembers the last filtered selection.

Comment: As I said, that was only (a randomly chosen) example. - anyhow if it's only copying the *filtered cells*, and you want it to copy *all* the cells, then the logical solution is...turn off the filter?

Comment: So I want the code to loop through selection of cells, filter them one by one and I want to copy the filtered cells and paste it on another column. Hence will have to keep the filter on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use advanced filter:

```
    Sheets("Emps").Range("A1:D8").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Emps").Range("F5:F6"), CopyToRange:=Range("A1:B1"), _
    Unique:=False
```

Data source to selectively copy:

[image]

Data destination copied:

[image]

Reference this *short YouTube video*; You can **record a marco to help** yourself **with the code** also:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGUKjXmEi2E

A more **thorough tutorial** is found here:

http://www.contextures.com/xladvfilter01.html

This tutorial shows how to get the **source data from outside Excel**:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4189-excel-dynamic-filter-to-new-sheet.html

This tutorial shows how to **split data values based on a column to different sheets** (Fruit column; Apple sheet, Pear sheet, etc.):

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2884-excel-save-filtered-data-new-sheet-workbook.html

**Side note:** your criteria needs the titles you are querying on just like the output needs the titles to know where to place the info. If it doesn't match correctly, Excel won't know what you mean. *Don't forget to update the range name!*

Before version:

[image]

After version:

[image]

Your code in this case is:

```
    Sub yourFilter()
        Range("Source").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "Sheet2!Criteria"), CopyToRange:=Range("Sheet1!Extract"), Unique:=False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this looks very interesting. I have tried using this but it gives an error. The whole code is only 2 lines which is great! Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BB34470").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AB2:AB12"), CopyToRange:=Range("BP1:BQ1"), _
    Unique:=False

Comment: Yes, it's a much cleaner way to process it. What error does it show? Can't fix an unknown. Please show some same data or a screenshot of what you have (source data) and what you want it to be. You can even link the file in dropbox.

Comment: It shows Runtime error 1004: The extract range has a missing or invalid filename. If this works then my whole code could be condensed into 3 lines which is brilliant. I haven't used dropbox before. But will see if I can attach the file or screenshot here.

Comment: Did you get that code by recording it as a macro? Did you test that line of code by placing it in a macro by itself? Is that when you got the error? If so, then study the "thorough tutorial" if not, then the error is in another part of your code.  If you stepped through the advanced filtering "manually" and didn't receive an error then you know it works and you must find the error elsewhere. Without seeing your data though it's only guess work on this end. Google "how to share a file from dropbox on stackoverflow" and you will find the answer. I can help you more then.

Comment: You sure that was "invalid filename" not field name? Can I get screen shots of the 3 ranges?

Comment: Hiya big apologies, yes it indeed is invalid field name. Sorry have been trying other things aswell from your links but couldn't get it to work. I am trying to figure out dropbox and will share it once I manage to get that up and running. many thanks.

Comment: The destination field names must match the source field names. They don't all have to be used and they don't have to be in order, but they have to be the same.

Comment: Sorry but I am not clear what the field names mean. I am looking up on google aswell. But can you please clarify what I need to do?

Comment: Look at the source and destination screenshots I provided. In the destination screenshots you see how I did not have to use all the source columns? Do you see they are not in order? But what you MUST do is have them exactly as they are in the source. Best method is to copy from the source to the destination so that no accidental space or other invisible character or misspell is introduced.  When the error you are getting occurs, that is the problem the majority of the time.

Comment: Try this: https://www.dropbox.com/help/files-folders/view-only-access#link
Search for "Share a link from dropbox.com"

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvrq1v9gt20q581/IS24_Jun17_base.xlsx?dl=0   hope this is better. thanks

Comment: Which is your source range,  where did you place your criteria range, and where do you want your output range?

Comment: Source Range:- Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:BB34470") CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AB2:AB12") Output:-Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("BP1:BQ1")

Comment: See the info at the bottom of my answer under "Side note." Please let me know how the changes work.

Comment: I created the named ranges exactly as your suggestions above, the code just runs through but doesn't seem to copy the filtered columns.

Comment: Try this one: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0tfwikfc4566nu4/IS24_Jun17_base.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! One of the best efficient and condense code. Working perfectly! Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated:)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You could thank me by marking it as the answer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `Select` and `Activate` which is not required when Autofiltering or copying a range. Instead declare some range variable, set it properly and use it.

After you have applied autofilter, maybe you are interested in copying the visible cells. Change the lines which are copying the ranges as below...

```
Range("AM1:AM34470").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Range("AU1:AU34470").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

Also `Selection.End(xlDown)` is not very reliable, it will stop once it finds an empty cell if any before the last cell in the column.

Comment: Hi, the copying visible cells only is very useful. I am just having the issue with Selection.Copy Destination:=Range("BQ1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) line of code. Its just overlapping everytime it copies a new range

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with that line. BTW try this `Destination:=Range("BQ" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)` and see if that works.

Comment: Its still giving the same output as the original code.